# django-channels 2.x How to implement login required on the consumer class?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I am using django-channels 2.1.2. Since it had a drastic change from 1.x to 2.x, I would like to know the way to enforce login on the  consumer class.

So far:

```
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer
import json

from channels.consumer import SyncConsumer
from doclet.models import *

class ChatConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def connect(self):
    to_room_id = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['to_room_id']
    self.user = self.scope["user"]
    if self.user.is_authenticated:
        if self.user.rooms.filter(pk=int(to_room_id)).exists():
            self.to_room = Room.objects.get(pk=int(to_room_id))
            self.room_name = 'room_%s' %self.to_room.id
    else:

        self.close() #do something to create room for the user


    # Join room group
    await self.channel_layer.group_add(
        self.room_name,
        self.channel_name
    )

    await self.accept()
```

Comment: I'd assume `AuthMiddlewareStack` should work. Where ever you're initiating the asgi app (ex. `routing.py`, `asgi.py`) wrap the `URLRouter` in a `AuthMiddlewareStack`

Answer (score 1):

You need to set this up in your Application stack.

```py
application = ProtocolTypeRouter({

    "websocket": AuthMiddlewareStack(
        URLRouter([
            url(r"^front(end)/$", consumers.AsyncChatConsumer),
        ])
    ),

})
```

And then in your `connect` method, you can access the user from `self.scope['user']` feel free to save this onto your consumer instance. By trying to read the `user` from the `scope` you will ensure a user object was resolved.

you can do this before calling `self.accept()` in the `connect` method if you so wish to ensure the WebSocket connection is not accepted if the user auth failed.